# enter a number in while loop in c by fgets

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I'm trying to get a number in a loop(again and again) from keyboard by `fgets`. but it is getting the number only in the first time of the loop. and later the program does not request the number again (I mean that she does not let me put in the number) and exit.

```
while(1){
    printf("Option: ");
    char buf[4];
    if(buf == fgets(buf,4,stdin)){
        int ret;
        ret = sscanf(buf,"%d",&num);
        if(ret!=1)
           exit(0);         
    }
}
```

Comment: How big was the number you typed? If you type more than 3 characters, the second call to `fgets()` will process the remainder of the input.

Comment: What is the input you provide? More than 99?

Comment: no just the numbers 1 or 2

Comment: Maybe it is a print issue? `printf` is line buffered and will not output until a newline is seen in the string or an `fflush` is called. Can you try: `printf("Option: "); fflush(stdout);`?

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Show the input you use, the corresponding actual output you get and the expected output. I cannot reproduce the problem with the code snippet from the question. See https://onlinegdb.com/SyIt1AJrd

Comment: Try `char buf[100]; ...  fgets(buf, sizeof buf ,stdin)` and see if the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able reproduce the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 4

int main() {
    while(1){
        printf("Option (terminate with non-number like enter): ");
        char buf[LEN];
        if(fgets(buf, LEN, stdin)) {
            int num;
            if(sscanf(buf,"%d",&num) != 1) break;      
            printf("Number was %d\n", num);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with an example session:

```
Option: 1
Number was 1
Option: 2
Number was 2
^C
```